# SQL ranking based on condition

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am trying to add another column called session_id. I want to rank according to the condition that if the time difference between the date_time is more than 30 minutes, then that will be counted as another session. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

| date_diff | date_time | session_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-01-18 00:01:40.000000 | 1 |
| 0 | 2023-01-18 00:01:42.000000 | 1 |
| 0 | 2023-01-18 00:01:46.000000 | 1 |
| 93 | 2023-01-18 01:34:38.000000 | 2 |
| 0 | 2023-01-18 01:34:38.000000 | 2 |
| 27 | 2023-01-18 02:01:59.000000 | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-01-18 02:02:00.000000 | 2 |
| 89 | 2023-01-18 03:31:40.000000 | 3 |

So whenever, date_diff in minutes is more than 30, that will be categorized as a new session.

Answer (score 4):

There might be a better way to do this in Redshift, which I don't have, but you might try something like this:

```
SELECT Datetime, date_diff, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN date_diff > 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY Datetime) AS group_id
FROM your_table
```

This simply flags the rows > 30 with a 1, and then the `OVER()` clause will sort and sum which would create the ordered session_id you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

One option uses a conditional window sum:

```
select t.*,
    1 + sum(case when date_diff > 30 then 1 else 0 end) 
        over(order by date_time) session_id
from mytable
```

If you wanted to compute the date difference on the fly from the timestamp column, we would use `lag()` first:

```
select t.*,
    1 + sum(case when datediff(minute, lag_date_time, date_time) > 30 then 1 else 0 end) 
        over(order by date_time) session_id
from (
    select t.*, lag(date_time, 1, date_time) over(order by date_time) lag_date_time
    from mytable t
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using window functions in SQL. Assuming you have a table called activity with the columns date_diff and date_time, you can use the following query to calculate the session_id:

```html
WITH
  time_diffs AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      LAG(date_time) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) AS prev_date_time
    FROM
      activity
  ),
  flagged_sessions AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      CASE
        WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (date_time - prev_date_time)) / 60 > 30 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END AS new_session_flag
    FROM
      time_diffs
  ),
  session_ids AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      SUM(new_session_flag) OVER (ORDER BY date_time) + 1 AS session_id
    FROM
      flagged_sessions
  )
SELECT
  date_diff,
  date_time,
  session_id
FROM
  session_ids
ORDER BY
  date_time;
```

In this query:

We first calculate the time difference between the current row and the previous row using the LAG window function in the time_diffs CTE.
Then, we create a new_session_flag column in the flagged_sessions CTE, which is 1 if the time difference is more than 30 minutes, and 0 otherwise.
Finally, we calculate the session_id by taking the cumulative sum of the new_session_flag column, and adding 1 to it in the session_ids CTE.
The final result is selected from the session_ids CTE and ordered by date_time.